# Delete values that are duplicate and move to another table

Tags: excel-formula, powerquery

I would like to create a table based on a visible one, in which there will be no duplicate values in column A and no duplicate values in the content of column B. What functions should pay attention to? I am asking for advice, I haven't found a function to remove duplicates + move to another table. The number of rows varies depending on the data source.

[image]

Comment: Are you ready to type some Excel VBA code ? Because I think you won't be able to achieve this only with standard Excel functions

Comment: will the content in Column B be different for each content in Column A? i.e will there be `h, h, i` and `h, h, j` for `1000` instead of `h, h, i` across board for `1000`? Also please let me know if you want to see an approach using **power query** which is a built in function of excel 2010 and later versions. If so please update your post to include `#powerquery` in the tags so other contributors can assist you if I am busy...

Comment: For each unique value in column A, the content in column B will be the same. For the value 1000 in column A, the content in column B will always be the same as in the example. Of course, that I want to know the power query I look through the documentation. thank you for the information, I will keep trying.

Comment: Give power query a go and if you encountered any problem you can update your post accordingly. If you are open to VBA as an option you can also update the tags and I am sure someone can help you on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically for you case you my use this code:

```
= Table.Group(YourTable, "A", {"B", each Text.Combine(List.Sort(List.Distinct(Text.Split([B]{0}, ", "))), ", ")})
```

But following code is more robust (since, there may be different values in each row of Column B):

```
= Table.Group(YourTable, "A", {"B", each Text.Combine(List.Sort(List.Union(List.Transform([B], each List.Distinct(Text.Split(_, ", "))))), ", ")})
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume your table is named `Table1`, you can do it this way:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Table.Distinct = Table.Distinct(Source),
    Text.Split     = Table.TransformColumns(Table.Distinct, {"B", (x)=>Text.Split(x, ", ")}),
    List.Distinct  = Table.TransformColumns(Text.Split, {"B", List.Distinct}),
    Text.Combine   = Table.TransformColumns(List.Distinct, {"B", (x)=>Text.Combine(x,",")})
in
    Text.Combine
```

[image]

If you like shorter version, then it can be as follow

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Table.Distinct = Table.Distinct(Source),
    Text.Distinct  = Table.TransformColumns(Table.Distinct, {"B", (x)=>Text.Combine(List.Distinct(Text.Split(x, ", ")),", ")})
in
    Text.Distinct
```